# asp.net + DataList

Tags: asp.net, datalist

Hello help me 
I need DataList with limited number of rows .. with out using RepeatColumns properties
so I need just one column in the DataList with limited number of Rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use repeat columns for row count, like this in the datalist:

```
RepeatColumns = "5"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [enter link description here][Enumerable.Take] on your DataSource and "Take" the number of rows you need.

Example from MSDN:

```
        int[] grades = { 59, 82, 70, 56, 92, 98, 85 };

        IEnumerable<int> topThreeGrades =
            grades.OrderByDescending(grade => grade).Take(3);
```

Comment: It would go after you retrieve the DataList's datasource (from wherever you do that).  Then you perform the LINQ query and use that as the DataList's datasource.